# How to use style for GroupBox header?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, styles

I have lost of `GroupBox` in my form that their header text must be **Bold**. I know how to do it for a single `GroupBox`:

```
<GroupBox>
     <GroupBox.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="HEADER TEXT" FontWeight="Bold"/>
     </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

But I'm interested to know how to do it with `Styles`. Here is what I have tried:

```
<Style TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource lightBlueBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25,1,5,5"/>
    //<Setter ??
</Style>
```

I have tried `<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value={StaticResource myTemp}>` Which `myTemp` is a simple `DataTemplate` But VS suddenly closed! I'm not sure if I'm in the correct way of doing it, so anyone could help me?

**EDIT:** Please test your idea before posting it as an answer!

Comment: LOL *Please test your idea before posting it as an answer!* - Please give us the information, so that we can help you. *Throwing an exception* is not enough. At least the content of the exception would be necessary to tell you, what's wrong.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Did you try the following?

```
<Style TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource lightBlueBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25,1,5,5"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<GroupBox Header="Title" />
```

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this, But the designer throws exception

Comment: Did you try what I posted? And what kind of exception is the designer throwing?

Comment: Did you changed your solution? I tried it and this time it works. Thank you.

Comment: No I didn't. But I'm glad I could help.

Comment: This breaks `HeaderStringFormat` functionality.

Comment: The accelerator (shortcut) key seems to be fixed by using a `Label` instead of a `TextBlock`.

Comment: I just changed `TextBlock` to `Label` and it worked. I had to set `Height="15"` for the label though because otherwise the `GroupBox`'s contents would look weirdo.

Comment: @HristoYankov: Uhm, why?

Answer (score 2):

A groupboxs headerTemplate is a type of DataTemplate. so you should provide a datatemplate object insteed of style or template.

try below one.

```
   <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <TextBlock Text="Test Templated Header"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox  Header="Test Header" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
            </Border>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: So the GroupBox's header would be "Test Header" or "Test Templated Header"

Comment: If you have some `GroupBox` with different Headers what will happen?

Comment: are you using any sort of binding in your datatemplate. if so please make it dynamicresource insteed of StaticResource.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but it's simply wrong, what you're suggesting. I don't see, how `DynamicResource` could help here. You're whole post is kind of misleading.

Comment: yes you are right it will not useful as we are using direct property values. as FontWeight="Bold" thanks for the cut.