# BorderBrush in wpf doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to replace this default border color in a groupbox but it doesn't work.

[image]

here code snippet:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="278" Margin="107,74,33,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="760">
  <GroupBox.Header>
    <Border  Background="#FFDAD5D5" BorderBrush="#FFDAD5D5" BorderThickness="56">
      <TextBlock Text="Installation data" />
    </Border>
 </GroupBox.Header>
```

Comment: Have you set the border brush of the group header instead?

Comment: It doesn't work even if I run the app

Comment: It works just fine for me. Make sure that you set the BorderBrush property of the correct GroupBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Style` definitions, like this: [How to use style for GroupBox header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808446/how-to-use-style-for-groupbox-header).

You can avoid, that any other style will override yours.
Besides your code gets a cleaner structure and you can re-use this style for other GroupBoxes.

```
<Style x:Key="MyGroupeBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="278"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="760"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="107,74,33,0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="#FFDAD5D5" BorderBrush="#FFDAD5D5" BorderThickness="56">
                    <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use it as follow:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" 
          Style="{StaticResource MyGroupeBoxStyle}" 
          Header="Installation data" />
```

Comment: Note that I changed the `TextBox` element to `Label`, because it has led to problems in the solution of the link.

Answer (score -1):

i think GroupBox is inside another control which overlays your Border.
Maybe you can try to place your GroupBox to the front - just to try

Let me know whats happening.

Greedings